# How do I include the full body field in the RSS feed for a taxonomy term?

Tags: views, 6, taxonomy-terms, feeds

How do I include the full body field in the RSS feed for a taxonomy term?

I tried enabling the default taxonomy view in Drupal, but it doesn't let me select any fields in the field list area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal 6:

The easiest way is to:

Change the setting in 
/admin/content/rss-publishing

Or:

1. Install views
2. Enable taxonomy_term view
3. Edit the 2 Feeds

   - Click on the gear right of *Row Style*
   - Change to full text

Comment: Doh! How did I not check rss-publishing? Thanks!